# On Potential Difference

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, mass-energy

We say that The work done on a coulomb of charge by the electric force from the terminals to move it from one point to another is called Voltage.Then my q is if I increase the length of the wire making the electrons move a longer distance to reach the bulb,then Work done should increase and the bulb should glow more brightly. But on increasing the length the voltage does not increase.Why does not that happen? and what is the correct definition of Potential Difference and what is this electric potential energy? Please clarify.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The opposite is happening. Voltage is not a force. The force concept is closer to electric fields, and the electric field is voltage divided by distance---if the wire is longer but the voltage stays the same, the electric field has decreased in such a way as to keep the voltage the same. If you push over a longer distance by a suitably decreased force, no wonder the work done is the same.

Comment: I'm no electromagnetism expert, but I would expect the bulb to glow slightly brighter when a shorter wire is used as it offers less resistance than a longer wire. $R=\rho L/A$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent's answer is right. This is one of the times that the water metaphor for electricity is appropriate: if a constant voltage is imagined not as electrical potential but the gravitational potential of a pool of water at the top of a hill, you will note that if we allow water to flow down over a long distance, the slope will me significantly more shallow than if it drops directly down. The force experienced by water on these paths depends on how long that path is (shallow = low force), but the total energy expended in getting the water down (potential difference) is the same.

Answer (score 2):

> if I increase the length of the wire making the electrons move a longer distance to reach the bulb,then Work done should increase

This is not correct. Recall that $W=\vec F \cdot \vec d$ and in electrostatics $\vec F = q \vec E$. So it is not the voltage that provides the force that does work, but the E field. The SI units for the E field is $\mathrm{V/m}$, so if you double the distance then your $\mathrm{m}$ doubles, so your $\vec E$ halves, so your $\vec F$ also halves. So you wind up with half the $\vec F$ over twice the $\vec d$ so your $W$ is unchanged.